# How to bind href to a function result?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

First, let me show the piece of pseudo-code to illustrate functionality I am trying to achieve

```
<a data-ng-href="{{getPath('InsuredProfileSummary',{insuredId:insured.insuredId})}}">Summary</a>
```

Basically, I have a routes defined so that I can refer to them by name, for example

```
 {
    name:'InsuredProfileSummary',
    url: '/insureds/:insuredId/profile/summary',
    config: {
               templateUrl: 'app/insured/profile/summary/inProfileSummary.html',
               reloadOnSearch: false,
                settings:{}
            }
 }
```

and I have a service that, given the route, builds the url. So in my example it would replace insuredId with the value, and one would get correct url to the insured profile. This works fine in controller, such as this code

```
 $scope.closeEditModal(vm.insured);
 var summaryPath = routesSvc.getPath("InsuredProfileSummary", { insuredId: vm.insured.insuredId });
 $location.path(summaryPath);
```

My question is how would one achieve this binding in html template. Is there a native way to bind result of a function to a value of the attribute, or do I have to write my own directive?

Comment: inside the ng elements in the html remove the brackets, they aren't necessairy, you can call an element from ng-click="something()" for example writing $scope.something

Answer (score 0):

don't see an issue here.

http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/2YkeH/

```
  $scope.genUrl = function(){
        return 'http://js4.it'
    }
```

Probably I didn't get the idea of the question.

If you want to update it asynchronously it's better to bind a model -
http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/2YkeH/6/

Comment: your example works, BUT, i think I have an issue that data gets loaded and the links do not get re-evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had an error, I was missing a "#" in the path, that is why the code did not work.